# What is a finite subcover of $[0,1]^{[0,1]}$?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, product-space

According to Tychonoff's theorem, under the standard topology, $[0,1]^{[0,1]}$ is compact. However, I cannot think of a finite subcover of this space. Also, how does this reconcile with the fact that if $K$ is a compact subset of $(0,1)^{[0,1]}$, then $K$ must only be a finite Cartesian product of compact subset of $(0,1)$? Why cannot $K$ be something like $[0.1,0.5]^{[0,1]}$? Or maybe I am missing something? Thank you very much!

Comment: When you write "I cannot think of a finite subcover of this space," what cover are you referring to? You can't have a subcover without specifying a cover.

Comment: The entire space is a finite open cover.

Comment: @copper.hat Gotcha! And any open cover of the space must include the entire space so that any open cover has finite subcover. And this reconciles perfectly with the second question I posted. Thank you so much!

Comment: You are missing something.  In a compact space, EVERY open cover has a finite sub-cover.

Comment: @AndrewLiu : You wrote "any open cover of the space must include the entire space so that any open cover has finite subcover." What does that mean?  The space as a whole need not be, and usually is not, a member of the open cover, and one cannot instantly deduce from "includ[ing] the whole space" that every open cover has a finite subcover (since obviously that is not true in non-compact spaces).  Your posting shows confusion about what the definitions are.  Before one can ask whether a _particular_ open cover has a finite subcover, one must have in mind some particular open cover. $\qquad$

Comment: @AndrewLiu: Slow down :-). The union of members of an open cover must cover the whole space, but that does not mean that the whole space is part of the cover.

Comment: @copper.hat Yeah I misunderstand the concept. I think I understand now. Or at least better than before. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You're right about the final point: in the (non-compact!) space $(0,1)^{[0,1]}$ (in the product topology) the subset $[\frac{1}{10},\frac{1}{2}]^{[0,1]}$ is indeed compact (by the same Tychonoff theorem); it is not true that we can only have a finite product of "compact component spaces"; you seem to be confused with *open* sets, where basic open sets depend on finitely many coordinates.

There are plenty of finite covers, but the point of compactness is that **every** open cover of $[0,1]^{[0,1]}$ has a finite subcover.

E.g. $U = \left\{f \in [0,1]^{[0,1]}: f(0)<  \frac{3}{4} \right\}$ is open, and so is $V = \left\{f \in [0,1]^{[0,1]}: f(0) > \frac{1}{2} \right\}$ and $U \cup V = [0,1]^{[0,1]}$, and we can do similar things with other finite covers on finitely many coordinates.

Comment: If K is a compact subset of $(0,1)^A$ then the projection $p_a(K)$ of $K$ onto its  $a$-th co-ordinate must be a compact subset of $(0,1)$ so $ p_a(K)$ is a closed subset of $[x_a,y_a]$ where  $0<x_a\leq y_a<1.$

Comment: @user254665 I know. But the OP doubted this.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thank you. I understand better now.